# How do I create a custom session in Google AppEngine using Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, session, session-variables

I'm having trouble with sessions in AppEngine. For some reason, every time I'm logged into my app, it kicks me out every 30-60 minutes, even though I set lifetime to 720 minutes in session.php in Laravel 5.2. I also created a new session handler. Below are my files.

app\Extensions\AppEngineStorageSessionHandler.php

```
namespace App\Extensions;

class AppEngineStorageSessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface{
private $savePath = '';

public function open($savePath,$sessionName){
    $this->savePath = 'http://example.com';
    if(!is_dir($this->savePath)){
        mkdir($this->savePath,0777);
    }
    return true;
}

public function close(){
    return true;
}

public function read($id){
    return (string)@file_get_contents($this->savePath.'/sess_'.$id);
}

public function write($id,$data){
    return (file_put_contents($this->savePath.'/sess_'.$id,$data) === false)?false:true;
}

public function destroy($id){
    $file = $this->savePath.'/sess_'.$id;
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
    return true;
}

public function gc($maxlifetime){
    foreach(glob($this->savePath.'/sess_*') as $file){
        if(filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time() && file_exists($file)){
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I created a new provider for this handler.

app\Providers\SessionServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Extensions\AppEngineStorageSessionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;

class SessionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Session::extend('gae_session', function($app) {
        // Return implementation of SessionHandlerInterface...
        return new AppEngineStorageSessionHandler;
    });
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

Lastly, I added this provider to the Providers array under config\app.php to the very end of the array.

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    App\Providers\SessionServiceProvider::class,
]
```

What am I missing? I've searched many, many hours and haven't found a workable solution. I've also tried calling `session_start();` on every page, and nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the filesystem for sessions, but the instances in App Engine are ephemeral. Instead, you should use cookie sessions or database sessions.

Cookie sessions can be implemented by setting `SESSION_DRIVER` to `cookie` in your `app.yaml`:

```
env_variables:
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Databsae sessions can be achieved by following the "Setting up Database Sessions" chapter of [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard#set_up_database_sessions)